# Ubuntu doesn't see raid0 SSD

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, raid, uefi

I want to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. I created two raid0 volumes from the BIOS/EFI, one for Windows and one for Ubuntu. Windows can see both volumes, and I can install it to a volume. However, Ubuntu cannot see any disks.

I also tried it without raid0, it did not see my Samsung 960 NVMe m2 disks.

My motherboard is a MSI z270 Gaming Pro Carbon.